# Spring Boot multi module project and bean creation order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a main module named `core` and other modules that defines Spring beans of type `Job`.

I'd like to have a `List<Job>` in my main module.

The problem is that the creation of the `@Service` class that contains the `@Autowired List<Jobs>` is happening prior to the creation of the Jobs in the other modules (which are a maven dependency in `core`).

How can I direct Spring to gather all Jobs into a list in the main module?

I tried to use `@Order` but it doesn't seem to make any affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating Job bean under configuration file.